# How can I choose which element is selected in a Gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I need something like

```
PageViewer.setCurrentElement(i)..
```

Anyone has got an idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int,%20boolean))

```
gallery.setSelection(0, false);
```

position is the index of the element (0-based) in your dataset. The boolean is for the animation